# having trouble using % in a vat calculator only getting inf and -inf in results

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float price, vat, vatless, vatprice;
    int vatpercentage;

    printf("Enter the price of the item:\n ");
    scanf_s("%f", &price);

    printf("what is the current vat:  \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &vatpercentage);

    vatpercentage = (float) (vatpercentage / 100);
    vat = (float) (vatpercentage * vatpercentage);
    
    vatless = price / vat;

    vatprice = price - vatless;

    printf("Total = %.2f\n", price);
    printf("Your vatless price is %.2f\n", vatless);
    printf("your vatprice is %.2f\n", vatprice);

    return 0;
}
```

Hello trying to make a vat calculator but I can't really figure out why I'm only getting inf and - inf when I try this code.

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and/or even add basic debugging print statements to examine the variable values. Specifically, have you had a look at `vatpercentage` value? Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Also, avoid `float` for this task.  Use `double`.

Comment: I don't understand why you multiply vatpercentage by itself in this line: `vat = (float) (vatpercentage * vatpercentage);`

Comment: You should not use floating points for economic calculations as it will yield rounding errors.

Comment: @Pablo If not done thoughtfully, integer calculations can yield truncation errors. Jus' saying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplicity is beneficial... I am lost in the tangle, computing values for 5 different variables with similar names.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    double price;
    printf( "Enter the price: " );
    scanf( "%lf", &price );

    int vat;
    printf( "Enter the VAT %%: ");
    scanf( "%d", &vat );

    double base = price * 100 / ( 100 + vat );
    printf( "Total%9.2lf\n", price );
    printf( "VAT  %9.2lf (%d%%)\n", price - base, vat );
    printf( "Base %9.2lf\n", base );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter the price: 68.95
Enter the VAT %: 13
Total    68.95
VAT       7.93 (13%)
Base     61.02
```

Error checking and validating the input have been omitted for brevity.

"Floating point" will (usually) be a *close approximation* of what we humans regard as "integer values". There may be values that are *shown* as "5.00", but, internally, the value is "4.9998". The user is warned and, with the inclusion of "math.h", computed floating point values should be rounded appropriately.

I don't have experience with "VAT", but I think these 3 variables are computing what you are seeking. Please let me know if this is wrong and I will delete this answer as quickly as possible.

Comment: With _money_, all 3 moneys should be rounded to the near base amount (e.g. 0.01).  For select prices and VAT, base money may not be possible that sums as desired.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've added a paragraph to the answer with a warning about floating point values. Thank you for checking up on me... "More sufficient unto the day" `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

`vatpercentage` is an `int`, so the division `vatpercentage / 100` is done as [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers). Define it as a `float` and you should be OK.